# When you make a question with a bounty, does it take away the points from you before you accept answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I would like to know if you lose points before or after awarding a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you make the bounty, you lose the points.

Answer (score 2):

Points are deducted as soon as the bounty is created/offered.

Answer (score 0):

The bounty is subtracted from your reputation when the bounty is started on your question by you.